# How to to check if the user inserted the date in this format week number and last two digits of the year in java

Tags: java

I want to check if the user inserted the date in this format
for example: String date = "1420";   where 14 is the week number of the year and 20 is the year 2020

I have created this method but it doesnt work. What is the correct pattern? Also can you share me a link or something where i can see these patterns.

```
public static boolean checkDate (String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("wwuu");
    try {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
        System.out.println("The string is a date and time: " + dateTime);
        return true;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.out.println("The string is not a date and time of format \"wwuu\" : " + dtpe.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get this message
The string is not a date and time of format "wwuu" : Text '1420' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {WeekOfWeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=14, Year=2020},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

Comment: "u" is day number in week, not anything related to year. You probably want pattern "wyy" or "wwyy" depending on 
if you want leading zeroes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: OP is using DateTimeFormatter  and not SimpleDateFormat. In DateTimeFormatter  u is the year: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: `u` is for *calendar* year. You need `Y` for a *week-based* year.

Comment: Your life would easier if you use the [ISO 8601 standard format for week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). Ex: `2020-W14`.

Comment: Tip: If doing much work with weeks, you may want to add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project for its [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'u' to specify the year does not seem to work. Instead you should use 'Y'. According to the documentation, this defines the "week-based-year" ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html ).

But there is still a problem with the formatter. By specifying a week and a year, there is no way for the parser to know which day of the week and which time of the day should be considered when parsing a date. You can use a
DateTimeFormatterBuilder to specify default values for the things that are not in the string to be formated. Here is your code adapted:

```
public static boolean checkDate (String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter =  new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("wwYY")
        .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue())
        .toFormatter();
    try {
      LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter).atStartOfDay();
      System.out.println("The string is a date and time: " + dateTime);
      return true;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
      System.out.println("The string is not a date and time of format \"wwuu\" : " + dtpe.getMessage());
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I defined the formatter to use Monday as the default day of the week. Then I formatted just a LocalDate and specified that I want this date "atStartOfDay".